# Проблемы с классом BarcodeWriter при формировании QR-кода

Tags: c#, wpf, zxing

Здравствуйте уважаемые специалисты. Решил использовать пробный вариант кода и посмотреть, как вообще формируются QR-кода в WPF, но столкнулся с тем, что видимо проект не видит класса BarcodeWriter. Честно говоря, думал, что все ограничится одним лишь пакетом ZXing, но похоже это не так. В чем может заключаться проблема - не понимаю. Дело в том, что данный класс все-таки должен содержаться в этой библиотеке, так как при удалении using ZXing, VisualStudio пишет, что нет такого пакета или пространства имен, а с подключенным пакетом: `базовый класс для конкретных устройств записи штрих-кодов с определенными форматами изображений штрих-кода`, т.е. он его видит. Еще пишет: `Использование универсального типа "BarcodeWriter<TOutput>" требует аргументы типа 1`. Возможно решение совсем на поверхности, но для меня это пока не понятно. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить, что необходимо поменять или добавить.

Файл .cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using ZXing;

namespace EmployeeSystem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для QR_code.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class QR_code : Window
    {
        public int ProductCode { get; set; }

        public QR_code()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnConvert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Drawing.Image img = null;
                BitmapImage bimg = new BitmapImage();
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    BarcodeWriter writer;
                    writer = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter() { Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE };
                    writer.Options.Height = 80;
                    writer.Options.Width = 280;
                    writer.Options.PureBarcode = true;
                    img = writer.Write(this.txtbarcodecontent.Text);
                    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    ms.Position = 0;
                    bimg.BeginInit();
                    bimg.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat;
                    bimg.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    bimg.UriSource = null;
                    bimg.StreamSource = ms;
                    bimg.EndInit();
                    this.imgbarcode.Source = bimg;// return File(ms.ToArray(), "image/jpeg");  
                    this.tbkbarcodecontent.Text = this.txtbarcodecontent.Text;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Файл .xaml для большей понятности:

```
<Window x:Class="EmployeeSystem.QR_code"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmployeeSystem"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="QR_code" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="QR Code Generator" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30"/>
        <TextBlock Text="QR Code Content :" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="txtbarcodecontent"/>
        <Button Content="Generate" Name="btnConvert" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100" Click="BtnConvert_Click"/>
        <TextBlock Text="QR Code :" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Name="imgbarcode"/>
            <TextBlock Name="tbkbarcodecontent" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/issues/370#issuecomment-967279786

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это решило проблему, кто мог подумать, что данный класс только так используют! Оформите пожалуйста комментарий, как ответ!

Comment: Можете оформить ответ самостоятельно.